# "Can't find definition of model" Error

Tags: ltspice

I am trying to use a custom diode model: 1N5228B. The same process worked fine with a different custom model diode.

This is the circuit:

[image]

This is the .lib file:

[image]

The .lib file is in the correct directory, the same directory as the .lib file for the other diode I used. Also, I would like to note that I tried a regular diode as well as a Zener.

Comment: please do not post a oicture of text ... post the text instead,

Answer (score 3):

That file is a subcircuit, if you look at the file that works I’ll bet it’s just got a model statement in it.

For a subcircuit you need to change the device prefix. Ctrl+Right Click the diode and change the prefix from D to X. Let us know if that works.

See [this article](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-using-an-intrinsic-symbol-for-a-third-party-model.html).

Comment: Here’s an official reference from Linear Tech in case it’s of any use to the questioner: https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-using-an-intrinsic-symbol-for-a-third-party-model.html

Comment: @SteKulov Thanks. Was posting from my phone so couldn't do a link at the time. Now added to the answer.